# Power BI calculating weighted average by month

Tags: powerbi, average

Have an easy one here but can't figure it out

| Month | Numerator | Denominator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 4 | 10 |
| Jan | 2 | 9 |
| Feb | 8 | 1 |
| Feb | 4 | 15 |

etc.

So the chart has month along the X-axis and then I would want the weight average for each column.

So Jan the average would be 6/19=32%, Feb would be 12/16=75%, etc. etc. --looking for a measure to capture the y-axis data

Answer (score 0):

Create a **Calulated Table** from the your 'Table':

```
Calulated Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Month],
    "Weight Average", 
        DIVIDE( 
            SUM('Table'[Numerator]), 
            SUM('Table'[Denominator])
        )
)
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: How could you do this without calculating a new table? How to calculate this value in an extra column in the original table?
thnx!